# Using Between clause with dates alongside the and clause as condition in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to retrieve data from consumptions table with the conditions applied in the query. When I echo the query in PHP and run it in MySQL returns this error: #1054 -

> Unknown column '2017-07-14' in 'where clause'

P.S: timestamp column datatype is datetime.

```
$drink = $_POST['drink'];
$user = $_SESSION['name'];
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
$selectquery = " SELECT * FROM consumptions 
                 WHERE (time_stamp >=`$from`  AND time_stamp<=`$to`) 
                AND user_name = `$user` AND `d_id` = `$drink`";
```

Any Help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you used ` instead of '

` is used for the name of columns not for the values

change to

```
    `SELECT * FROM `consumptions` 
     WHERE (`time_stamp` >= '$from' AND `time_stamp` <= '$to') 
     AND `user_name` = '$user' AND `d_id` = '$drink'";)`
```

also in MYSQL you can use

```
WHERE `time_stamp` BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'
```

and also your code is vulernable to sql injection.

Comment: Just figured it out. Came to stackoverflow to delete the question and saw your answer. Anyways Thanks @Robert.

Answer (score 0):

SQL:

```
$selectquery = "SELECT * FROM consumptions 
                WHERE (time_stamp BETWEEN `$from`  AND `$to`) 
                AND user_name = `$user` AND `d_id` = `$drink`";
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.